# XAML - how to put Runs as an ItemsControl ItemTemplate?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm building a comment feature, and the "mentions" in the comments have special behaviors.

The comment is broken up into parts: `Hey @Bill look at @Ted!` would become `Hey`, `@Bill`, `look at`, `@Ted`, `!`.

I'm trying to use an `ItemsControl` to display these comment parts.  I'd like to set the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` to be a `Label` or similar, then inject `Run` elements into that template, but the XAML throws a parsing exception.

---

Here's a rough example of what I'm playing around with:

```
<Style x:Key="CommentBody" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="...">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Paragraph />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Run Text="Hello" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Is this the correct approach to the problem?

*Edit* Also, maybe it's worth mentioning that I've tried a horizontal `WrapPanel` for the template, with `TextBlock`s as the items, but then the content inside textblocks doesn't wrap, only the items themselves.

Comment: Why don't you just put the Runs in the `Inlines` collection of a TextBlock?

Comment: That seems great - how do I control the items source property? I don't know how many Runs will be there....and I have to switch depending on if it's a mention or plain text.

Comment: I'd look at writing an attached property that targets Paragraph. Bind a collection of strings to it, it populates Inlines. If you want fancy stuff like formatting, that gets more complicated. But you're not going to be doing it with ItemsControl since Paragraph isn't a Panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a basic approximation of this with an attached property that'll create the Runs and add them.

```
<Style x:Key="CommentBody" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <FlowDocumentReader>
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph local:ParagraphExt.Runs="{Binding}" />
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </FlowDocumentReader>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
public static class ParagraphExt
{
    #region ParagraphExt.Runs Attached Property
    public static System.Collections.IEnumerable GetRuns(Paragraph obj)
    {
        return (System.Collections.IEnumerable)obj.GetValue(RunsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRuns(Paragraph obj, System.Collections.IList value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RunsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RunsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Runs", 
            typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable), typeof(ParagraphExt),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, Runs_PropertyChanged));

    private static void Runs_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pgh = d as Paragraph;

        pgh.Inlines.Clear();

        if (e.NewValue is System.Collections.IEnumerable ienum)
        {
            foreach (var item in ienum)
            {
                //  If you're doing "markdown" style formatting, all you need
                //  in the enumeration is strings. All the brains goes in here. 
                pgh.Inlines.Add(new Run($"{item}"));
                pgh.Inlines.Add(new Run($" "));
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion ParagraphExt.Runs Attached Property
}
```

Usage. `Words` is a `List<String>` property of the viewmodel.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Words}" Style="{StaticResource CommentBody}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ed! I'd been fiddling with something like this as well but it's good to have some confirmation.  Unfortunately I'll need the formatting but maybe I can keep digging and figure something out.

Comment: fairly complex, needs a highlight, hover behaviors, and a popup on the user's name.

Comment: @Ben It’ll be a bit of work but I don’t think any of that’s out of reach. I’d look at adding additional attached properties to set styles for the above loop to apply in various cases.

Comment: Sounds good - yeah looks like there will be some external static resources, etc.  Will accept since probably headed this direction anyway. Thanks for the help!